# Loading Sentinel 2 images into ArcGIS Mosaic Dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mosaic-dataset, arcgis-10.4, sentinel-2

I'm attempting to add Sentinel 2 images to a new mosaic dataset in ArcGIS 10.4.

AddRastersToMosaicDataset reports success, but there Errors reported in the messages and the result is that the images are not added to the mosaic dataset.

I've ensured that the path length for the files are <256 (https://geonet.esri.com/thread/173068):

> Please look to shorten the path by truncating part of the directory
>   name that contains .SAFE at the end. All the details in the directory
>   name are part of the metadata, so such a long directoy name is not
>   required.

It appears to successfully find, but is unable to open the raster and removes it.

```
Messages
Executing: AddRastersToMosaicDataset C:\ssdvol1\GISData\s2test\sentinel_2016.gdb\sentinel_2016_md Sentinel-2 M:\S2A_MD_TEST\S2A_OPER_PRD_MSIL1C_PDMC_20160206T011622_R098_V20160204T175251_20160204T175251.SAFE\S2A_OPER_MTD_SAFL1C_PDMC_20160206T011622_R098_V20160204T175251_20160204T175251.xml UPDATE_CELL_SIZES UPDATE_BOUNDARY NO_OVERVIEWS # 0 1500 # *S2A*.xml SUBFOLDERS ALLOW_DUPLICATES NO_PYRAMIDS NO_STATISTICS NO_THUMBNAILS # NO_FORCE_SPATIAL_REFERENCE NO_STATISTICS #
Start Time: Tue Mar 22 13:41:23 2016
2016-03-22T13:41:25.799: Loading raster datasets
2016-03-22T13:41:25.829: Completed crawling 1 data source items. Added 1 mosaic dataset items.
2016-03-22T13:41:25.830: Synchronizing crawled data source items
2016-03-22T13:41:25.844: Synchronizing items associated with raster type instance 'Sentinel-2' [ID: 10].
2016-03-22T13:41:25.862: Error: 80042019: Could not build mosaic dataset item. [ID: 3, URI: 'M:\S2A_MD_TEST\S2A_OPER_PRD_MSIL1C_PDMC_20160206T011622_R098_V20160204T175251_20160204T175251.SAFE\S2A_OPER_MTD_SAFL1C_PDMC_20160206T011622_R098_V20160204T175251_20160204T175251.xml|MS']
2016-03-22T13:41:25.862: Error: 8004203f: Could not open source as a raster dataset. [M:\S2A_MD_TEST\S2A_OPER_PRD_MSIL1C_PDMC_20160206T011622_R098_V20160204T175251_20160204T175251.SAFE\Granule\S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_MTI__20160204T212051_A003241_T13SDD_N02.01\IMG_DATA\S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_MTI__20160204T212051_A003241_T13SDD_B01.jp2]
2016-03-22T13:41:25.865: Error: 8004205e: 1 mosaic dataset items could not be built.
2016-03-22T13:41:25.865: Removing invalid mosaic dataset items
2016-03-22T13:41:25.876: Removed 1 mosaic dataset items and 0 unreferenced raster type instances.
2016-03-22T13:41:25.948: Removing broken mosaic dataset items.
2016-03-22T13:41:25.958: Removed 0 mosaic dataset items and 0 unreferenced raster type instances.
2016-03-22T13:41:26.032: Completed synchronization: 1 items selected, 0 items synchronized.
Succeeded at Tue Mar 22 13:41:26 2016 (Elapsed Time: 2.66 seconds)
```

Is there something I need to do to the sentinel directory or files in order for ArcGIS to add it to mosaic dataset?

Comment: This is probably something to ask Tec Support.

Comment: I did this morning.  I wanted to get a co-worker to confirm my result and to attempt the same thing with 10.3.1 Raster Type Cumulative Patch (also a fail, but not in the same way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the Add Raster failure came down to the source of the downloaded product.  I thought it was ESA Sentinel-2. But unbeknownst to me, I was actually testing data a combination of USGS-distributed full-resolution and tiled Sentinel 2 products. Both fail to add in ArcCatalog 10.4, also confirmed by the Esri Tech Support analyst.

Once I purged the USGS test data, and downloaded the Sentinel-2 products directly from: https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1, I was able to successfully add the Sentinel-2 SAFE directory to the mosaic dataset (At this time, I can't confirm that anything else works with regards to the mosaic dataset. But I can add them successfully).

I am currently downloading a file from https://scihub.copernicus.eu/s2/odata/v1 to test (*if anyone can confirm these load into an ArcGIS 10.4 mosaic dataset, please leave a comment...because these copernicus download speeds are painful*).

---

**Update on 10.3.1 Raster Type Cumulative Patch**:
I was able to get Sentinel-2 to load, but not with the same options as 10.4.  In 10.4, you select File-->Select the product xml inside the SAFE directory

In 10.3.1 you select Workspace-->then select the SAFE directory itself:

[image]

Comment: Jay, could you describe this workflow in more detail please? I'm having trouble getting Sentinel 2 data to work well. Downloads often fail and if they succeed I get CRC errors unzipping them. Trying to mosaic the broken files does not work.